# Remove old permissions in django

Tags: django

In my Django site there are some permissions entries linked to applications that I've removed. For example I have permissions entries linked to "Dashboard" and "Jet" applications. How can you remove them?

Comment: Write a migration, query the Permission objects and call delete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To start, make an empty migration file:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

Change the migration (this is an example, adjust to your needs):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals    
from django.db import migrations    


def add_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    pass


def remove_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    """Reverse the above additions of permissions."""
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    Permission = apps.get_model('auth.Permission')
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
        model='somemodel',
        app_label='yourappname',
    )
    # This cascades to Group
    Permission.objects.filter(
        content_type=content_type,
        codename__in=('add_somemodel', 'change_somemodel', 'delete_somemodel'),
    ).delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(remove_permissions, add_permissions),
    ]
```

Comment: Note: if the permission was a custom one created in a previous migration, you need to run this in a separate `migrate` command because the objects are created only after **all** the migrations are applied (thus you would receive a `DoesNotExist` error when reaching `Permission.objects.filter`)

Comment: i tried the above solution to remove default model permissions, but it didn't work. I currently have both default and custom created permissions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nikhil  This question and answer are about removing old (stale) permissions. If you try to delete default permissions from an existing model, you'd might want to set the Model.Meta.default_permissions to an empty list. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#default-permissions

Answer (score 25):

Permissions have foreign keys to content types under the hood, so removing the content types for the models that no longer exist will also remove the permissions for those models.

Fortunately, Django also provides a `manage.py` command to remove old content types: [`remove_stale_contenttypes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#remove-stale-contenttypes). Running that command will list the content types that no longer exist and the related objects (including permissions) that will be deleted, allowing you to review the changes and approve them.

```
$ manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes
Some content types in your database are stale and can be deleted.
Any objects that depend on these content types will also be deleted.
The content types and dependent objects that would be deleted are:

    - Content type for stale_app.removed_model
    - 4 auth.Permission object(s)

This list doesn't include any cascade deletions to data outside of Django's
models (uncommon).

Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
```

Comment: This management command also takes an optional argument ``--include-stale-apps``: "Deletes stale content types including ones from previously installed apps that have been removed from INSTALLED_APPS." (quoted from the command help text).

Answer (score 3):

I did it this way:

```
import re 

for perm in Permission.objects.all():
    if re.match( r".+modelname.+permissionname.+",str(perm)):
        print(perm)
        perm.delete()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have custom or model based (default) permissions you wish to remove you could write a command like this to accomplish this task:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import django.apps

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Remove custom permissions that are no longer in models'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # get the db name needed for removal...
        database_name = input('Database Name: ')

        default_perm_names = list()
        # are real perms in db, may not be accurate
        db_custom_perm_names = list()
        # will be used to ensure they are correct.
        meta_custom_perm_names = list()

        default_and_custom_perms = list()

        for model in django.apps.apps.get_models():
            # add to models found to fix perms from removed models
            app_label = model._meta.app_label
            lower_model_name = model._meta.model_name

            all_model_permissions = Permission.objects.using(database_name).filter(content_type__app_label=app_label, content_type__model=lower_model_name)


            default_and_custom_perms.extend([x for x in all_model_permissions])
            # get the custom meta permissions, these should be in the meta of the class
            # will be a list or tuple or list, [0=codename, 1=name]
            meta_permissions = model._meta.permissions

            if meta_permissions:
                for perm in all_model_permissions:
                    # will be the model name from the content type, this is how django makes default perms
                    # we are trying to remove them so now we can figure out which ones are default by provided name
                    model_name_lower = perm.content_type.name
                    # default_perms =  ['add', 'change', 'view', 'delete', 'undelete']
                    # append them to the list of default names
                    default_perm_names.append(f'Can add {model_name_lower}')
                    default_perm_names.append(f'Can change {model_name_lower}')
                    default_perm_names.append(f'Can view {model_name_lower}')
                    default_perm_names.append(f'Can delete {model_name_lower}')
                    default_perm_names.append(f'Can undelete {model_name_lower}')
                    # will mean this is a custom perm...so add it
                    if not perm.name in default_perm_names:
                        db_custom_perm_names.append(perm.name)

                # the perms to ensure are correct...
                for model_perm in meta_permissions:
                    # get the meta perm, will be a list or tuple or list, [0=codename, 1=name]
                    custom_perm = Permission.objects.using(database_name).get(codename=model_perm[0], name=model_perm[1])
                    meta_custom_perm_names.append(custom_perm.name)


        perms_to_remove = [perm for perm in db_custom_perm_names if perm not in meta_custom_perm_names]
        if not perms_to_remove:
            print('There are no stale custom permissions to remove.')


        # print(perms_to_remove)
        # now remove the custom permissions that were removed from the model
        for actual_permission_to_remove in Permission.objects.using(database_name).filter(name__in=perms_to_remove):
            # print(actual_permission_to_remove)
            actual_permission_to_remove.delete(using=database_name)
            print(actual_permission_to_remove, '...deleted')

        for perm in [x for x in Permission.objects.using(database_name)]:
            # loop all perms...if it is not in the model perms it does not exist...
            if perm.content_type.model not in [x.content_type.model for x in default_and_custom_perms]:
                perm.delete(using=database_name)
                print(perm, 'regular permission...deleted')
```

If you also wish to ensure that the default permissions are added from Django you can add this snippet in the command:

```
    from django.apps import apps
    from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions
    from apps.client.models import ClientInformation
    # add all permissions the django way
    # get the db name needed from settings.py
    database_name = 'default' # or whatever DB you are looking for
    print(f'adding all permissions if not there to {database_name}')
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        # print(app_config)
        app_config.models_module = True
        create_permissions(app_config, using=database_name)
        app_config.models_module = None
```

Then call via `python manage.py fix_permissions` if you name your command file `fix_permissions.py`

Comment: I love this solution because it allows you to clean up the permissions anytime. The accepted solution is ok if you apply it from start of your project. Another drawback of the accepted solution is that you must not forget to add the migration script and do not make a mistake in it either...
This solution also works more user-friendly than the one supplied by Django: `remove_stale_contenttypes`.

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked @ViaTech's code to use Django's `contrib.auth.management._get_all_permissions()` functions which makes it more straight forward:

```python3
from typing import List, Set, Tuple

import django.apps

# noinspection PyProtectedMember
from django.contrib.auth.management import _get_all_permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Remove custom permissions that are no longer defined in models"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--database",
            default=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS,
            help=f'Specifies the database to use. Default is "{DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS}".',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "--dry",
            action="store_true",
            help="Do a dry run not actually deleting any permissions",
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options) -> str:
        using = options["database"]

        # This will hold the permissions that models have defined,
        # i.e. default permissions plus additional custom permissions:
        #       (content_type.pk, codename)
        defined_perms: List[Tuple[int, str]] = []

        for model in django.apps.apps.get_models():
            ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(
                model, for_concrete_model=False
            )

            # noinspection PyProtectedMember
            for (codename, _) in _get_all_permissions(model._meta):
                defined_perms.append((ctype.id, codename))

        # All permissions in current database (including stale ones)
        all_perms = Permission.objects.using(using).all()

        stale_perm_pks: Set[int] = set()
        for perm in all_perms:
            if (perm.content_type.pk, perm.codename) not in defined_perms:
                stale_perm_pks.add(perm.pk)
                self.stdout.write(f"Delete permission: {perm}")

        # Delete all stale permissions
        if options["dry"]:
            result = f"DRY RUN: {len(stale_perm_pks)} stale permissions NOT deleted"
        else:
            if stale_perm_pks:
                Permission.objects.filter(pk__in=stale_perm_pks).delete()
            result = f"{len(stale_perm_pks)} stale permissions deleted"

        return result
```