# Extra tables in Django's admin group permission list

Tags: django, django-admin, django-migrations, django-database

I have run a few fake migrations yesterday and also renamed a few tables of my database direcly yesterday due to foreign key constraints and other similar errors Django kept throwing at me after renaming some models.

I know this is not standard procedure and it's prone to messing up things. It did solve everything for me though, without the need of wiping out the database, as I was almost resolved to do.

Anyway, as I said, all is working great, expect for the list shown in the 'available permissions' in the Group management. The following (and other) tables are not in the database, and indeed are not even prepended with the applications's name:

[image]

Where are those sourced from? How can I get rid of them?

Comment: These are stored in the `auth_permission` table. Connect to the databse with database manager like Dbeaver so you can view/delete them.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: PS: I cannot remove those rows due to primary key constraints I suppose. The tables they refer to do not exist though. Is it safe to force-delete them, or is there a way of resetting that auth_permissions table?

Comment: You can delete the constraints too. But make sure you know what you're deleting. Do a backup first.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use django shell to get ride of old permissions like this :**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

# Assume that you have all name of the old permissions  to delete in a list
permission_old = ['permission_name_1', 'permission_name_2', ...]

for perm in Permission.objects.all():
    if str(perm) in permission_old:
        print(perm)
        perm.delete()
```

**Or** read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182012/remove-old-permissions-in-django)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially for linking that post where I discovered the existence of the `remove_stale_contenttypes` option, which did what I was looking for.