# Django manual migration to add group

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am attempting to create a migration that will automatically add a group and permissions to the group when it is run. I adapted some code from the docs and an example. I can get the migration to add the group but not the permissions. I am getting the following error: `TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use permissions.set() instead.`
I am not sure how to implement this suggestion. Any ideas?

The migration:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions



def add_group_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        create_permissions(app_config, apps=apps, verbosity=0)

    # Employee
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Employee')
    if created:
        permissions_qs = Permission.objects.filter(
                         codename__in=[
                                         'can_add_how_to_entry',
                                         'can_change_how_to_entry',
                                         'can_view_how_to_entry',
                                                      ]
        )
        group.permissions = permissions_qs
        group.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_group_permissions),
    ]
```

Comment: Do you 100% need to store this data change in a migration? I've found in use, personally, that data migrations introduce mostly just complexity... Can you not set the required fields via some type of 'root util' and then ensure everything moving forwards is accurate?

Comment: Thanks ViaTech, I will look into that route. I am learning that migrations do introduce a number of complexities.

Comment: However, since I am working on a multi-tenant project and the migrations will run each time a new tenant is created, I wonder if migrations aren't the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: for example I have a system that has multiple clients with multiple DBs. I have a task that runs right after each deployment to ensure both Admins get all permissions and that my permission tables are accurate. Please look at a post I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65633047/8382028 and check the section on `create_permissions()`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `group.permissions` is a related query manager, not a field, so if you assign something to that you will destroy it. So you need to do something like:

```
permissions_qs = Permission.objects ...
for permission in permissions_qs:
    group.permissions.add(permission)
group.save()
```

Additionally, the Django way to create custom permission is through the Meta class, for example:

```
# Assuming that you have an "Entry" model

class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
        permissions = [
            ('custom_permission_a', 'a description for permission a'),
            ('custom_permission_b', 'a description for permission b'),
        ]
```

After migrating the changes you will have two additional permissions attached to the `Entry` model.

Now you can create a group with the custom permissions like:

```
group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='CustomGroup')
if created:
    permissions = Permission.objects.filter(
        codename__in=[
            'custom_permission_a',
            'custom_permission_b',
        ]
    )
    for p in permissions:
    group.permissions.add(p)
    group.save()
```

You can include that in a new migration or whatever you want, also if you don't want to use the Meta class to create your custom permissions, you can do it programmatically:

```
# Assuming that you have an Entry model

# Import Entry model

from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

entryContentType = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Entry)
 
# Create custom permission
custom_permission = Permission.objects.create(
    codename ='custom_permission',
    name ='description for the custom permission',
    content_type = entryContentType
)
```

A `custom_permission` will be created and attached to the `Entry` model. Then you can include that permission in your custom group.

Comment: I tried this but the permissions were still not added. Maybe I am not using formatting the permissions correctly. In the admin panel an example of a permission is: "tenant_howto|how to entry|Can add how to entry"

Comment: I think your permissions were not created correctly, I include more details in my answer